# Лучшая структура хранения фраз для печати

Tags: python

Вопрос наверное немного расплывчатый и каждая ситуация индивидуальна, но я не нашел никакого упоминания об этом вопросе.
Какой лучший способ хранить фразы для печати? Лист? Словарь? Итератор?

Сейчас я имею такой код, но наверное это не лучшее решение ...

```
dialog = {
'rus' : {
'common' : ['Нажмите "Enter" для подтверждения.', 'Что-то пошло не так :(',
'Повторить попытку', ],
'maintree' : iter(['\nВсего файлов для уничтожения:', '\nВы уверены, что\
 хотите безвозвратно уничтожить файл', '\nВсего файлов для уничтожения: ', 
'Следующий файл был успешно уничтожен: ', '\nВсего уничтожено файлов: ',
'\Уничтожить еще файлы? ']),
```

Comment: Во-первых, gettext-файл с переводами фраз. Во-вторых, какую задачу вы вообще решаете и зачем вам понадобилось выносить фразы в отдельную переменную? Чем `print('Нажмите "Enter" для подтверждения.')` не угодило?

Comment: Фразы не единожды встречаются

Comment: @ДавидШико, лучший вариант - хранить фразы на месте, где они используются. Сейчас просматривая свой код, чтобы понять что у вас выводится на месте `print(dialog['rus']['common'][2])` нужно сначала найти dialog, правильно я понимаю? В чем выгода? Если нужна локализация - используйте [gettext](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gettext), про который писали выше.

Comment: Параметры очень длинные выходят, вызов 1 функции расползается на 3 строки, вот в чем проблема. А так оно тихонько лежит в начале кожа, никому не мешает. + Какие то фразы дублируются даже в вызове 1 ф-и.

Comment: "Параметры очень длинные выходят, вызов 1 функции расползается на 3 строки, вот в чем проблема." - добавьте пример кода в вопросе. Сейчас такое впечатление, что вы просто усложняете себе жизнь.

Comment: "Фразы не единожды встречаются" - а что мешает их написать не единожды? По-моему фразы - это не то, где стоит избавляться от дубликатов, мания дедуплицировать всё до чего руки дотянутся может сделать только хуже

Answer (score 1):

в общем-то все равно. Однако, с точки поиска по индексу, список медленнее поиска по ключу в словаре.  Кроме того, при определенной сноровке текст программы будет мнемоничнее именнно со словарем, как вы и выбрали.
Кроме того, через словарь в Python часто реализуют отсутствующую структуру типа `switch` или `case`, благодаря чему например поддержка вашей проглядывающей  мультиязычности будет изящнее.